# Typescript : Adding types to a function that takes in a string and returns a different promise based on the string

Tags: typescript, promise, interface

I have a function that takes in a string and based on the string hits different APIs to fetch images.

I have solved it by writing an interface and then as the return type of the function, it returns a `Promise<Interface>` as shown in the code below.

```js
    interface IAnimal {
      image?: string | null
      message?: string
      status: string
    }
    const getAnimal = async (inAnimal: string): Promise<IAnimal> => {
      const isDogWord: boolean = ["dog", "Dog", "DOG"].includes(inAnimal.trim())
      const isFoxWord: boolean = ["fox", "Fox", "FOX"].includes(inAnimal.trim())
      let result: IAnimal = { image: null, status: "tofetch" };
      if(isDogWord) {
        result = await fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random").then((data) => data.json());
        if(result.status === "success") {
          return {
            image: result.message,
            status: result.status
          }
        }
      }
      if(isFoxWord) {
        result = await fetch("https://randomfox.ca/floof/").then((data) => data.json());
        return {
          image: result.image,
          status: "success"
        }
      }
      return {
        image: null,
        status: "failure"
      }
    };
```

This solves the typescript errors but I am not happy with making the image and message optional in the Interface. I am receiving `{ "message": "image__link", "status": "success or failure" }` from dog API and `{"image": "image__link", "status": "success or failure"}` from the fox API. Is what I have done the right approach or do we have a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the interface `IAnimal` is not what those apis return. You want to return that interface from your function, but those APIs should have their own interface representing the response data.

```
interface DogApiResponse {
  message: string
  status: string
}

interface FoxApiResponse {
  image: string
}

interface Animal {
  status: string
  image: string | null
}
```

To generalize the set of available animal types I propose to also add interface for the fetching part of individual APIs.

```
declare type RandomAnimalFactory = () => Promise<Animal>
```

Now we declare two factories - for dogs and foxes

```
const dogFactory: RandomAnimalFactory = async () => {
  const result: DogApiResponse = await fetch(dogApiUrl).then(data => data.json())
  if (result.status !== 'success') {
    throw new Error('Dog API railure')
  }
  return {image: result.message, status: 'success'}
}

const foxFactory: RandomAnimalFactory = async () => {
  const result: FoxApiResponse = await fetch(foxApiUrl).then(data => data.json())
  return {image: result.image, status: 'success'}
}
```

The we can have the named animal factory work like this

````
declare type NamedAnimalFactory = (name: string) => Promise<Animal>


const createRandomNamedAnimalFactory = (randomFactories: {[key: string]: RandomAnimalFactory}): NamedAnimalFactory => {
  return async (name) => {
    const factory = randomFactories[name.trim().toLowerCase()]
    if (!factory) {
      return {image: null, status: 'failure'}
    }

    try {
      return await factory()
    } catch {
      return {image: null, status: 'failure'}
    }
  }
}

const getAnimal: NamedAnimalFactory = createRandomNamedAnimalFactory({
  dog: dogFactory,
  fox: foxFactory,
})
```
````